# Blocking VPN connections with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

First I don't even know if this is possible, but I currently have a method to block banned users from viewing my website.

```
<script src='https://www.l2.io/ip.js?var=ip' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='application/javascript'>
var bannedips=["XX.XXX.XXX.XX", "XX.XXX.XXX.XX", "XX.XXX.XXX.XX", "XX.XXX.XXX.XX"]

var handleips=bannedips.join("|")
handleips=new RegExp(handleips, "i")

if (ip.search(handleips)!=-1){ 
   window.stop();
}
</script>
```

The above works flawlessly when an IP Address is added into the `bannedips` portion, but I'm wondering how I can just block all `VPN` connections?

Comment: Your method won't work for people who have JavaScript turned off of course, or for people who outfit their browsers to strip that code out etc.

Comment: An in-browser block via Javascript?! That's… fairly trivial to "work around". I'll just add `l2.io` to my ad blocker.

Comment: Also, you're publishing a list of all banned IPs to your website…?!

Comment: Also, `.` in a regex means "anything", so you could get quite some surprising results from that naïve regex.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

There's no difference between a request that has been routed through a VPN and one that has not.

It isn't practical to get an exhaustive list of VPN endpoint IP addresses, and many of them are shared with non-VPN users anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For those arriving here via Google: If you need something accurate, you'll need to pay for an API. If you don't need high accuracy, then there are public lists which you can use which will catch *most* VPN IPs, but certainly not all of them, and you'll have false negatives.

I needed something with just half-decent accuracy for a project (just to make anonymous vote manipulation harder) so I whipped together this which uses a few public VPN/bot lists which update daily:

https://github.com/josephrocca/is-vpn

```js
import { isVpn } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/josephrocca/is-vpn@v0.0.2/mod.js";

let ip = "123.123.123.123";
if(isVpn(ip)) {
  // do something (but remember, it could be an inaccurate classification - see readme)
}
```

Also worth noting: Cloudflare offers TOR blocking for free, but VPN blocking requires Enterprise.

Also, there are many, very legitimate uses of VPNs - arguably everyone should be using a VPN, so if you're blocking them, you should have a *very* good reason.